# MVC Passing Data while opening a page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm fairly new to MVC 5, I know how to pass data from my entities to a single view but I am now trying to create a button that opens a new view and also passes some info.  I was wondering what some good ways to do this are.

I have model Position that has
positionId,
positionName,
positionDescription,
storeLocation

and a second model that is a job application

I want to create a button in my position details index that will open my application create page and pass in the positionId to be used locally in the application.

So my thought is to create a constructor for application that takes an int Id and use a this.appliedPositionId = id;  or something like that.  The issue is I'm not sure how to pass that info using a button to the view.  I've tried Redirect and RedirectAction but I think I am using them wrong.

Comment: Use `@Html.ActionLink()` and pass the values as route parameters (and style it to look like a button if thats what you want)

Comment: okay I'll try that, thank you

Comment: I'm having an issue passing the value, should I be using the model => model.PositionId syntax like they do above?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "yourController", new { id = Model.PositionId }, null)` assuming you have a `public ActionResult Create (int id) { ... }` method

Comment: Thank you so much that worked.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "yourController", new { id = Model.PositionId }, null)
```

assuming you have a public `ActionResult Create (int id) { ... }` method –

Stephen Muecke answered solved it, thank you.